# Could we consider having a "Code Review" tag?

Tags: discussion

Since https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/ is considered general QA for Sitecore, would there be any objections to having a `code-revew` tag so people could post snippets of code for review and suggestions, similar to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - it doesn't seem necessary to have a codereview.sitecore.stackexchange (as there would not be enough demand I'm sure) and it might be nicer to keep sitecore related code reviews in sitecore.stackexchange instead of the general code review SE site.

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote without a comment? I'm totally open to accepting reasons why this might *not* be a good idea, but it would be useful to have an explanation.

Comment: I think we have an upset; over a downvote/vote-to-close situation - almost all new questions get 1 downvote ;-)

Comment: That's the spirit ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without putting words in Matthews mouth; I'm almost certain it was implied that this would be more like a "is this code the right approach for an item:saved handler, or am I missing something?" type of code-review. And I think it would be a great idea.

I propose a tag something like `please-review`

Comment: Agreed that is a good idea

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thanks mark

Answer (score 2):

I think that these things would already be covered by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - I don't see the need for a specific Sitecore version of that.

What benefits would it give us?

Comment: You could make the same argument about Stackoverflow and Superuser... I think part of the idea is consolidation of information and community.

Comment: Totally agree, just going of the info @mark-cassidy put up about what the SE guys will be looking for.

Comment: I agree with Richard on this. There is a distinction between "please review my code" and "I'm trying to do X, this is what I have so far, is this the correct approach". The sites that cover this already exist for a reason.